# PG:InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR when trying to make an INSERT on stage database

Tags: heroku, insert, permissions, rails-postgresql, heroku-postgres

Im using heroku and postgres. Local is working fine but whenever the user (any user) performs an INSERT on stage it crashes. This is the message i get:

```
PG:InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied for relation .. INSERT INTO..
```

I granted privileges to public on the required tables but it doesn´t make a difference. Any insight would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve it? I just experience the exact same problem. No idea where to start digging.

Answer (score 24):

I know it's waaaaay late, but I just ran into this issue and I believe the problem is that you have exceeded the number of rows allowed for your DB. In my case, I was using a Hobby-dev plan and the limit is 10k rows. If you run `heroku pg:info` you will see something like:

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Hobby-dev
Status:      Available
Connections: 4/20
PG Version:  9.3.3
Created:     2014-05-27 15:07 UTC
Data Size:   175.5 MB
Tables:      47
Rows:        409300/10000 (Write access revoked)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
```

With the `Write access revoked` being the key piece of information. Upgrading your DB (or deleting some data) should solve this.

Comment: Wow thank you. I've been banging my head on this one for hours.

Comment: CLUTCH ANSWER!!

Comment: i upgraded my DB but i'm still getting the error. please help

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem caused by over 10000 rows, I was using Hobby Dev (free until November 2022), I upgraded to Basic (paid), I understand this might not be solution for everyone

Hobby Dev 10,000 row limit
Mini 10,000 row limit
Basic 10,000,000 row limit

https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql

Once I upgraded
[image]